# extract parts of a text line into multiple variables in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, dictionary

I have created a program that uses the dictionary object to read a line for a TXT file and  populate 2 listboxes. It is a bilingual dictionary.
In the file the lines have the structure:

key^value     (word in 1st language and word in 2nd language divided by the ^ separator)

e.g.
before^prima
later^dopo
hello^ciao

and the code works just fine...
the problem is that i now need to transform it in a multilingual dictionary so the structure would be

key^value1^value2^value3 (words in 4 languages all divided by the separator)

but i am not able to adapt the dictionary object to it.

How would you solve this?
Basically i have a bunch of lines that are formed by 4 parts with separator and i want to store all the 4 parts in 4 variables:
- definition
- 1stlang
- 2ndlang
- 3rdlang

The code i am using so far for the bilingual is this:

```
Public Class aero_dictionary

Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Private Sub Form1_Deactivate(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Deactivate
    Me.Opacity = 0.6
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Activated(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    Me.Opacity = 1
End Sub
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As System.Object, _
                          e As System.EventArgs) _
                        Handles Button1.Click
    Using OFD As New OpenFileDialog
        With OFD
            .Filter = "Dict files (*.dict)|*.dict"
            If .ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                LeggiDizionario(.FileName)
            End If
        End With
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub LeggiDizionario(FullPathFileName As String)

    Dim lines As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(FullPathFileName)

    For Each line As String In lines
        Dim kv As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) = ToKeyValuePair(line)
        dict.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(kv.Key)
    Next

End Sub

Public Function ToKeyValuePair(pair As String) _
                               As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)

    Dim two As String() = pair.Split("^")
    Return New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(two(0), two(1))
End Function
Private Sub listbox1_Click(sender As Object, _
                                       e As System.EventArgs) _
                                     Handles ListBox1.Click
    Dim lst As ListBox = DirectCast(ListBox1, ListBox)
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox2.SelectedText = dict(lst.SelectedItem)
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

You can define the dictionary to use an array of strings, then add the array of 3 elements (less the key) when you the `dict.Add`.

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String())
```

Comment: you mean like dict.add(kv.key, kv.value(0), kv.value(1), kv.value(2))